# Shutdown function causes reboot

Tags: applescript

I'm running Big Sur on a new T480 laptop and porting over a shutdown script from a different laptop running Mojave. The script is assigned to F5 using Quicksilver and can't be simplier.

```
tell application "System Events"
    shut down
end tell
```

Shutting down works 100% of the time (laptop turns off) but in 70% the laptop reboots and bios starts again. Reboot doesn't happen in Mojave.

Applescript coding isn't my forte so I tried a different script to select Shut Down... from the Apple menu but that produces

"error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu bar 1." number -1728 from menu bar 1"

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1
        click
        click menu item "Shut Down..." of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Hoping for some guidance to either of the approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The menu bar is not independent, it belongs to an application process, such as the **Finder**.  **System Events** is a faceless background app that provides access to various functions and attributes, including terms and events for controlling processes.

A menu item can also be a menu, which contains menu items, and so on, so the full hierarchy needs to be used.  Another thing to watch out for is that menu item titles typically use an ellipsis punctuation mark rather than periods, so your script can be reduced to something like:

```
tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Shut Down…" of menu "Apple" of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder"
```

There is also the [shutdown](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/restart-computers-apd7d247a89-3560-4c3b-a471-3e66ff607040/2.11/mac/11.0) command, but you may need to check the bios settings, as the **Finder** menu, **System Events** command, and shell utility all essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Your explanation is spot on and helps fill my vast Mac OSX ignorance. As a PC guy, I enjoy the Mac OS and learned lots from Hackintosh builds.

Thank you again for the highlight of the day.

Comment: I tried replacing my 2nd version of code with the single statement you provided and run it within Script Editor. The laptop doesn't shutdown (nothing seems to happen). The Results panel repeats the statement in a slightly different order. Am I doing something wrong.  Results  menu item "Shut Down…" of menu "Apple" of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder" of application "System Events"

Comment: It works for me, although I am running Monterey.  You might try testing with one of the other menu items, such as "About This Mac" or "App Store…".  If those work, you might have to patch or replace the the power interface (ACPI) kext - it’s been a while since I’ve run a hackintosh.